# Conditions for repair at Apple Store

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, repair, warranty, apple-store

Last time I was in an Apple Store, they suggested they could repair the Super Drive on my MacBook Pro (2010) when I next came in. Of course, it is out of warranty, so there will be a charge.

But, are there any conditions in order for them to perform a repair? Since I bought the laptop I have replaced its memory from the standard 4GB to 8GB. If it were still under warranty, is this something they would refuse to repair for (void)?

Do they have any conditions in order for them to repair, even when out of warranty?

Comment: Please consider both options. Repair at Apple will cost you over 200€

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

You should [Google for a replacement and do it yourself](http://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-8x-SuperDrive/IF185-040).

Apple will charge you way more than repairing it yourself. You don't have warranty, so why don't just do it yourself? If you fail, you can still go back to them because you're paying.

**Option 2**

You could also consider buying an [USB superdrive](http://store.apple.com/nl/product/MD564ZM/A/apple-usb-superdrive) instead. It will be much cheaper, and you could eventually replace the SuperDrive with an Optibay so you can add a second HDD (or SSD)

Comment: It had completely slipped my mind that I could perform the repair myself. Thanks for the guide.

Comment: I would say the DIY option is not so clear cut. It's very easy to screw up the DIY in such a way as to make the store repair much more expensive (tearing a ribbon cable, breaking a connector, damaging the logic board, etc). Plus, the store probably won't agree to install a replacement part supplied by you - they'll want to sell you a fresh one from their stock.

Answer (score 4):

You should have no problems since you are paying for the repair anyway. Plus, upgrading the RAM on a MacbookPro does not void your warranty.